# html select multiple choice input, store them in mysql db and search for matches

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My question first and then (many...infos): 
what are my options thinking of usability and speed when i want a user to be able to select mulitple answers from a dropdownbox, save them on their profile, then let other users key in their searchcriteria (can be multiple again) and finally find users by those mutiple searchcriteria?

The infos:
At the moment i am busy with a part of my website being a matchmaking system, much like datingsites use.

(I am using Mysqli, PHP and jQuery for my site)

I am using a dating site as an example to elaborate on my question: user A fills in his/her profile and enters their preference for a certain car brand: BMW, Volkswagen and Mercedes. User B wants to search the site for members who like BMW and/or Mercedes.

My original idea was to let user A fill in an input multiple html field and store it as an array (or comma-separated) in one column in my db. Then figure out how to select-search through that column which has stored arrays in it for user B.

So basically user A can enter multiple car brands in their profile and user B can give their criteria being also multiple car brands; the select query should fetch any row for matching criteria.

The input-field multiple looks like:

```
<tr><td>Which car brand(s) do you like?</td><td>
<select multiple name="CarBrandPref[]">
   <option  value="BMW"             > BMW</option>
   <option  value="Ford"            > Ford</option>
   <option  value="Mercedes"        > Mercedes </option>
   <option  value="GMC"             > GMC</option>
   <option  value="Volkswagen"      > Volkswagen </option>
   <option  value="Toyota"          > Toyota </option>
   <option  value="Audi"            > Audi </option>
</select>
</td></tr>
```

The profile table lay-out would be something like:

```
 Id     Name            CarbrandPref
--------------------------------------------------------
 1      Mike            bmw,volkswagen,mercedes
 2      Paul            Mercedes, ford, GMC
 3      Axel            GMC, ford, toyota, audi
 4      John            ford, bmw
```

User B would give searchcriteria 'bmw and mercedes'. The query should then return 3 rows:

```
Id     Name            CarbrandPref
---------------------------------------------------------
1      Mike            bmw,volkswagen,mercedes
2      Paul            Mercedes, ford, GMC
4      John            ford, bmw
```

Upon my searches on SO and other sites to get this working i noticed everyone saying that this (storing in arrays in db) was bad for performance etc. etc. Furthermore i can't get the select-search through the arrays in mysql to work.

So now i'm at a loss what to do. I don't want to add a column for each possble carbrand, but what to do else? Is there anyone who can help me with this? Any ideas are much appreciated!

I hope this is clear enough for someone to help me. If it is not, please tell me and i'll add the requested info.

I have used these links to be able to store the dropdownbox-populated arrays into the mysql database:

http://www.aleixcortadellas.com/main/2009/03/20/492/

http://toolspot.org/how-to-store-array-mysql.php

Comment: What part do you want to get working? Have you managed to save the data in the database? Please show something you have tried.

Comment: i have followed (amongst others) this tutorial for saving the arrays into a mysql datbase: http://toolspot.org/how-to-store-array-mysql.php. Also, i have tried to get Find_in_set working. But storing an array or comma-seperated values into one column seems to be a big no-no for procedural and perfomance reasons, so i've read...

Comment: At least this post in SO http://bit.ly/13Qw908 claims that comma-separated lists in MySQL are bad, however I see none of the reasons listed _there_ affecting your case.

Comment: @ threeFourOneSixOneThree:  done, i agree. Bit long but i did not know how to ask my question any shorter, sorry!

Comment: @Pietu199:  thx for the url although i had read that site already; which got the idea in my head that i was going the wrong way with storing mutiple answers in one field. However, only option i see left is to make seperate mysql-columns for each answer and given the fact that there are quite a few select mulitple inputs on my form, and i don't think that's ok to do...

Comment: So as far as i understood you are asking at least three things: **1) User Interface solution for selecting multiple options from a dropdownbox 2) Database: How best to store the selected options 3) Database: How to match selected options / find intersections of selected options.** 

Is my understanding of your question correct?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: yes, that's about it. I bit much i know, but i have been thinking and googling for it all day and i think i'm in need of help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three choices.

The first is to go down the path you are one and try to compare two comma delimited lists.  This produces really, really ugly SQL.  It does not allow indexes.  The basic idea is something like:

```
where find_in_set(substring_index(@list, ',', 1), CarBrands) > 0 or
      find_in_set(substring_index(substring_index(@list, ',', 2), ',', -1), CarBrands) > 0 or
      . . .
```

The second is to introduce a new table, which has one row for a user and a favorite whatever.  Let's make this general, so there is a column for the user, a column for category ("CarBrand") and a name.  Then the query looks something like:

```
from Profile p left outer join
     Favorites f
     on p.userId = f.userId and f.Category = 'CarBrand'
group by p.userId
having sum(f.Name = 'Mercedes') > 0 and
       sum(f.Name = 'BMW') > 0;
```

The third option is to use full text search and the `match` function.  The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

My guess is that a full text index is probably the easiest way for you to do what you want.

EDIT:

The query about full text index versus option 2.  Probably the key question has to do with stop words and short terms.  The full text index, for instance, drops words with less than 4 characters (by default, you can change both of these).  It also has a list of stop words.

My personal inclination would be to use the second option.  But the reasons may not be good ones.  It uses standard SQL and I'm comfortable with the data structures and queries.  So, it gives me more control over the results.

In your case, the full text search is probably easier to implement quickly and would very likely be as fast or faster.  The full text search also lets you do more complex booleans, such as mixing "AND" and "OR" and doing natural language search to get a relevance value.

Comment: Great infos thanks! i am reading though it and the url you provided. One question already though: option 2 will leave me with a seperate table in which all possible favorite combinations are placed and then save the id of the combination at hand in my original table? Is that also faster / preferable over option 3 or not? Option 3 seems to be easier but not sure if it's the most sensible to do.

Comment: i will learn soon enough :-) i am switching back and forth between option 2 and 3. 3 seems easier and less tables but i am not quite convinced it is the way to go. Maybe i'm just seeing ghosts! i will do some more reading.

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree: i have tried to upvote several answers here but i can't as i do not have enought reputation credits :( and as for accepting an answer: i will do that certainly when i have one that i can go with. Right now i'm considering the answers given and testing things. So, i will accept soon!

Comment: @Dave33 Sorry i was unaware that [upvotes require a min rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

Comment: No problem! I'm gonna go with option 3: match. Got it working now and for the time being it is fine. I am much more aware that i should use option 2, thank you all for pointing this out to me! but for practical reasons match will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a third table to map between users and car marques. The table will have a primary key covering two columns, each of which is a foreign key to one of the other two tables. The presence of a row in this table mapping between "Bastian" and "BMW" means that he has chosen that marque. Absence of such a row means no association exists.

More specifically, table 1 has users, table 2 has car brands. each of those have a primary key column with an id #. The third table links these two. See [Many-to-Many Relationships in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632965/many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql) and [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Understanding_SQL_Many_to_Many_Relationships.aspx) and [here](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-write-many-to-many-search-queries-in-mysql-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thx for your help. I think i understand but not quite sure. So there will be a third table which houses all possible combinations of carbrands or do you mean something else?

Comment: ok ok ok! I'm trying to get a grip on this info. Am i correct in saying that following this i do not store a reference to the CarBrand in the profile table anymore but for every carbrand chosen by user 2 i insert a new row in the new table (userID + chosen carbrand)? (the Carband in that table is only a reference to a third table) I do wonder how many tables i would get if i have like 15 different dropdownboxes on my form..

Comment: yes, that is the "most correct" way to do it, but as others have said, other mechanisms may be more practical, such as a set. it depends on how many car brands you have, and whether or not users of the database can add their own, or if the list is fixed.

Comment: many thanks for your help and the infos, i've learned alot and will use it in the future i'm sure. I cannot upvota you still, i tried...sorry!

Comment: @Dave33 Now you can :) You need 15 points to be able to vote up ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). I just up-voted your question so you should now have enough.